# Bloch Hamiltonian and density matrix

Tags: condensed-matter, second-quantization

The Bloch Hamiltonian is usually defined for periodic condensed matter systems in the absence of interactions. In momentum space, the full Hamiltonian of the system takes the form:

$$\mathcal{H} = \sum_\textbf{k} \Psi^{\dagger} H(\textbf{k})\Psi$$

where $\Psi$ is a column vector of annihilation operators and $H(\textbf{k})$ is the Bloch Hamiltonian. As the system is noninteracting, the important physical information is contained in the Bloch Hamiltonian and in many cases (for example when studying the topology of the system) we do not consider the full second-quantised Hamiltonian at all.

At thermal equilibrium, the density matrix of such a system takes the form:

$$\rho = \frac{e^{-\beta \mathcal{H}}}{Z}$$

which for noninteracting systems will be a gaussian state. The "proper" procedure would be to take the full second-quantised Hamiltonian in the exponential, however, since in theory all of the information of the system is contained in $H(\textbf{k})$, I was wondering whether taking the Bloch Hamiltonian is sufficient and at all physically meaningful.